# L4.2: Read config value in Unit Test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to access a config value from within one of my unit tests as such without any success (`Fatal error: Class 'Config' not found in...`):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= Config::get('text.max_links_per_job'); $i++) {
            $photosArray[] = array('link' => 'http://www.test.com/test'.$i.'.txt');
        }
```

However, in the same file I am setting a config value successfully, like this:

```
 Config::set('database.connections.client.database', 'test_db_dev');
```

If it is of any help, this is my `setUp()` :

```
public function setUp()
    {
        $this->createApplication();
        parent::setUp();

    }
```

Seems quite bizzarre that I can set a config value but I cannot read value, so any thoughts are more than welcome.

Comment: Have you included namespace?

Comment: No, I have not included namespace in my test. Would not this break for `Config::set()` too?